# what does last visit refers to which place in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361862/synopsis)

> Trevor stumbles back to Stevie's. She is dismayed by the extent of his injuries and urges him to see a doctor, which he refuses to do. Stevie is ready to let Trevor move in with her and find a regular job, until Trevor spots the picture of Ivan with Reynolds, and accuses Stevie of plotting against him with Ivan. Stevie tells him the photo is of Reynolds and none other than Trevor himself. She also has no idea who Ivan is. **She says that Trevor left the picture after his last visit.**

*His last visit* refers to a visit to what place?

Answer (score 1):

Stevie is saying that the reason the picture is there, in her home, is because Trevor left it there. So we can reasonably assume that the last visit took place at Stevie's home. That's how he was able to leave it there.